# How to delete beginning of the string in matrix?

Tags: r, string, matrix

Let's consider matrix following:

```
example_matrix <- matrix(c("group1_A", "group2_B", "C", 
                           "group11_E", "group3_F", "O", 
                           "K", "J", "Letter"), ncol = 3, nrow = 3)

     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]    
[1,] "group1_A" "group11_E" "K"     
[2,] "group2_B" "group3_F" "J"     
[3,] "C"        "O"        "Letter"
```

What I want to do is to delete in preceding `"group"` in matrix element if present.

So I want to end up with:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]    
[1,] "A"  "E"  "K"     
[2,] "B"  "F"  "J"     
[3,] "C"  "O"  "Letter"
```

My first idea was to use code:

```
> apply(example_matrix, 2, function(x)  gsub("group\\d_", "", x))
     [,1] [,2]        [,3]    
[1,] "A"  "group11_E" "K"     
[2,] "B"  "F"         "J"     
[3,] "C"  "O"         "Letter"
```

But as you can see there is `"group_11"` within it (code doesn't see it, because there are two numbers after "group").  And if I to

```
apply(example_matrix, 2, function(x)  gsub("group\\d\\d_", "", x))

     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]    
[1,] "group1_A" "E"        "K"     
[2,] "group2_B" "group3_F" "J"     
[3,] "C"        "O"        "Letter"
```

Then it will change properly `group11_`, however will left other ones.

Of course I can do some if for this case, however it's not so elegant solution (and what if I have more integers in number? e.g. `group11234_`)

Is there any possibility to do this simply?

Comment: Use wildcard for digits after group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `sub` with a `+` after `\\d` and starting with `^`.

```
sub("^group\\d+_", "", example_matrix)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]    
#[1,] "A"  "E"  "K"     
#[2,] "B"  "F"  "J"     
#[3,] "C"  "O"  "Letter"
```

In the given case removing everything until `_` will also work:

```
sub(".*_", "", example_matrix)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]    
#[1,] "A"  "E"  "K"     
#[2,] "B"  "F"  "J"     
#[3,] "C"  "O"  "Letter"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(example_matrix, 2, function(x)  gsub("group\\d+_", "", x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(example_matrix[], 2, function(x) gsub("^[^A-Z]+", "", x))
```